# Force delete folder (on NAS)

Tags: terminal, macos, nas

Running macos11 and have an old WD MyBook NAS that I'm trying to clear out some very old content (for example an old backup of Library/Mail/ folder). These folders have a LOT of files/folders within them. I having difficulty in force deleted the parent folder and everything within it.

Even if I try this in terminal

`Yes | rm -rf /path/to/folder`

I'm still getting errors such as:

`Directory not empty`

`No such file or directory`

Is there another command I can just that will just zap that folder?

edit:

if I run `ls -ld` on some of the files that error I get:

```
ls -ld '/Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/Mail Lost+Found/Mailboxes/*Solisitated Mail.mbox'
drwxrwxr-x  1 [user]  staff  264 15 Sep 21:48 /Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/Mail Lost+Found/Mailboxes/*Solisitated Mail.mbox

ls -ld '/Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/V2/Mailboxes/technology.mbox/tv.mbox/8EB56E50-58FF-45AF-A16F-FCAAACB943C9/Data/5'
drwxrwxr-x  1 [user]  staff  264 26 Sep 20:35 /Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/V2/Mailboxes/technology.mbox/tv.mbox/8EB56E50-58FF-45AF-A16F-FCAAACB943C9/Data/5

ls -ld '/Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/V2/IMAP-[email address]@[imap server]/[Gmail].mbox/All Mail.mbox'
drwxrwxr-x  1 [user]  staff  264 26 Sep 20:35 /Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/V2/IMAP-[email address]@[imap server]/[Gmail].mbox/All

ls -ld '/Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/V2/x'
drwxrwxr-x  1 [user]  staff  264 15 Sep 22:00 /Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/V2/x
```

if I run it on the aboves parents I get

```
drwxrwxr-x  1 [user] staff  568 26 Sep 20:34 /Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/Mail Lost+Found/Mailboxes

drwxrwxr-x  1 [user] staff  264 27 Sep 20:10 /Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/V2/IMAP-[email]@[server]/[Gmail].mbox

drwxrwxr-x  1 [user] staff  264 26 Sep 20:35 /Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/V2/Mailboxes/technology.mbox/tv.mbox/8EB56E50-58FF-45AF-A16F-FCAAACB943C9/Data

drwxrwxr-x  1 [user] staff  568 16 Sep 18:54 /Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/V2
```

the user listed is the username I use to connect to the NAS not the user of the admin account on the mac.

Comment: @roaima that command just gives me 100's of lines of re: `/path/to/folder/etc/etc/: Directory not empty`. The bulk of the folders are empty although a few do have an invisable file `.index.ready` in them

Comment: rm -R /path/to/folder gives me `override rw-rw-r--  [user]/[group] for /path/to/folder/.filename?` or `No such file or directory` or `Directory not empty` which is why I started including `yes`

Comment: @roaima that command just gives me 100's of lines of re: /path/to/folder/etc/etc/: Directory not empty.

Comment: @roaima done that

Comment: @roaima did that, question updated. Now they all come back with `drwxrwxr-x  1 [user]  staff  264 [date] [path]`

Comment: We're getting somewhere. For one or more of these listed directories please would you now also run `ls -ld` for the parent directories. As an example for the first one it would be `ls -ld '/Volumes/Public/backup_mail/Mail/Mail Lost+Found/Mailboxes'`

Comment: @roaima done that

Comment: it seems files/containers give `drwxrwxr-x  1 [user] staff  264` whilst folders give 'drwxrwxr-x  1 [user] staff  568`

Comment: `rm -fr` would not need a pipe of continuous yes answers; maybe `rm` is aliased; did you try `\rm -rf` instead?

Comment: @U.Windl `\rm -rf '/Volumes/Public/backup_mail'` gave me just hundreds of /path/to/folder: Directory not empty

Comment: @CuCo Then your `rm` command is severely broken, or your OS is.